# Running python script on Android over SSH

Tags: android, python, ssh

I have a simple python script which uses standard input/output, and I would like to:

1. Open a SSH connection from my desktop computer to my Android device
2. Execute this python script on the device over the SSH session

So far I've found a SSH server app on the Play Store, which allows my to fullfill the 1st point. Then I have copied the script to the device, but I can't run it: there doesn't seem to be a python interpreter.

Is there any simple (non-root) way to execute a text-only (no GUI) python script on Android ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly ? No. You could use [Termux](https://termux.com/). 
It has a python package that is preinstalled (2.7.x though).